# SQL Query - Select date only

Tags: sql

I have a select query.

```
SELECT 
    NEXT_SUN = DATEADD(day, (8  + @@DATEFIRST - DATEPART(dw, '2016-11-22 10:38:34.260')) % 7, '2016-11-22 10:38:34.260' )
```

From this query I want to select only date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `CONVERT` with `DATE` option.

`SELECT NEXT_SUN = CONVERT(DATE,DATEADD(day, (8  + @@DATEFIRST - DATEPART(dw, '2016-11-22 10:38:34.260')) % 7, '2016-11-22 10:38:34.260' ))`

You can also use [Format()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213505.aspx) to get the desired result. If you want your return value to be converted into varchar you can do that also using `CONVERT`. More details on this are [here](http://sqlhints.com/2013/07/14/how-to-get-date-part-only-from-datetime-in-sql-server/)

Answer (score 1):

Just convert it to `date` data type from `datetime`  using `convert` or `cast` function.

```
 SELECT NEXT_SUN = convert(date,DATEADD(day, (8  + @@DATEFIRST - DATEPART(dw,
                              '2016-11-22 10:38:34.260')) % 7, '2016-11-22 10:38:34.260' ))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT NEXT_SUN = CAST( DATEADD(day, (8  + @@DATEFIRST - DATEPART(dw, '2016-11-22 10:38:34.260')) % 7, '2016-11-22 10:38:34.260' ) AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this also and get different format by date code at last in `CONVERT` function

```
SELECT 
NEXT_SUN = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(day, (8  + @@DATEFIRST - DATEPART(dw, '2016-11-22 10:38:34.260')) % 7, '2016-11-22 10:38:34.260'),101)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try..

```
SELECT NEXT_SUN = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(day, (8  + @@DATEFIRST - DATEPART(dw, '2016-11-22 10:38:34.260')) % 7, '2016-11-22 10:38:34.260'),101)
```